# Any Firefox extensions that track how long I stay on a web page?

Tags: firefox-extensions, time-management

I want to analyze my web surfing habits, and could use something to monitor how long I stay on a page with seconds precision.

Anything like this?

Answer (score 4):

Mee timer-2.0-3.0,comes with a patch to work above ff 3.1+
The Mee timer will lists each webpage and how long you have visited it, provides logs and does not appear to share info. with outside sites.
'Mee timer 2.0-3.0'-mozilla add ons-the download and patch instructions are on this page.The patch [below the review label.] has readable instructions, but could do with some more detail [at least for my needs]-Sorry i nave not been able to get the test to work but that could be me and not the patch.
If you wish to give the patch a go  mee timer could meet your needs.
https://addons.mozilla.org/af/firefox/addon/5168/

Comment: This is soooo close to what I need, but not quite. It does a bad job of recording individual sites (it only records the domain), and only records minute precision. I was hoping for something that tracks seconds and every domain I visit.

Comment: Er, every page*, not every domain that I visit. It already does that.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Try [about:me](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13681/). It does not monitor how long you stay on one page, but it can track the visits you pay to it per hour. You should give it a spin.

Comment: I clear my history and downloads when I exit the browser.

Answer (score 1):

[LeechBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4476/) is mainly for blocking sites, but it also has statistics about site usage.

Comment: I want to monitor every web page I go to, not specific lists that I define.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Mozilla Firefox addon, but will do the job:

[Manic Time.](http://www.manictime.com/) works very well, highly recommend.

it tracks everything on your computer...including the window titles of all the webpages you have been to...

Comment: I was hoping for something that integrates with Firefox, because I would also like to have the URL and differentiate between domains (so I can track how long I'm on an individual page, as well as browsing different pages within the same domain)

Comment: @Corey: it tracks in the window titles, so if the window titles *change*, it records that as a new page...regardless of the domain...and it says how long you've been there...

Answer (score 0):

There is [PageAddict](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3685/).

> PageAddict is a Firefox extension that will help you monitor 
>   your Internet addiction. Once 
>   you install it, choose PageAddict from the 
>   Tools menu to display a summary of the time 
>   you've wasted on each web site for this day, and a graph of your web...

Comment: According to the comments, their host website is dead and the extension relies on it to function. Bummer, because it looked like what I was hoping for.

Comment: Indeed. I tried it, and the menu entry brings me to a parked domain.

Answer (score 0):

May be time tracker will help you.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1887/

Check that out

Comment: This doesn't differentiate between web pages or anything. It just monitors how long you've been using Firefox per session.

Comment: No, it won't. `Planned feature: - Track time individually for specified sites`.

Comment: Planned features:
- Track time individually for specified sites
- Get back to work alarm
- Statistics

Comment: This also hasn't been updated since July 14, 2009. I'm guessing the project is dead.

Answer (score 0):

[RescueTime - Productivity Meter for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rescuetime-for-firefox/):

> RescueTime sits in the background and
> **measures which site is in focus and
> for how long.** It automatically stops
> measuring if your mouse and keyboard
> aren’t used for 2 minutes or more. It
> also allows you to manually stop
> measuring via a “pause” button. We
> show you your total Firefox time, what
> percent of your browsing is
> “productive”, and how your browsing
> productivity compared to hundreds of
> thousands of users across the world.
> You can check out **detailed browsing
> stats to see how much time you spend
> on individual web sites** and apps,
> which days your most productive on,
> and more.

Comment: I don't want an add-on that tracks and sends it to someone's server. I'd rather the information be kept private.

Answer (score 0):

[mind-the-time](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mind-the-time/) still seems active in 2021 although there are documented limitations